# trigger after delete is not compiling and i have no idea

Tags: mysql, sql

The code below is not compiling by HeidiSQL in a MYSQL base

```
BEGIN

    if NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM pedido_itens WHERE ID_PEDIDO = OLD.ID_pedido)
        DELETE from pedido WHERE pedido.ID = pedido_itens.old.ID_PEDIDO;
        END if;
END
```

I'm trying to create a trigger to remove from the "pedido" table when there are no more items in the "pedido_itens" table. But I can't compile, I don't understand where I'm going wrong. Thanks in advance for all help.
I'm new in the area.

Comment: Provide COMPLETE trigger text, not only its body. Also provide con=mplete error message text.

Answer (score 1):

I got it, had to change some details. But mostly the "then" was missing

```
    BEGIN

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) pedido_itens WHERE ID_PEDIDO = OLD.ID_pedido) >0 THEN
    
        DELETE from pedido WHERE pedido.ID = OLD.ID_PEDIDO;
        END IF; 
    END
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

with if statement you should use 'then',it is for what action you want to perform against your if.

```
BEGIN
        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) pedido_itens WHERE ID_PEDIDO = pedido_itens.OLD.ID_pedido) > 0 
        THEN
            DELETE from pedido WHERE pedido.ID = pedido_itens.OLD.ID_PEDIDO;
            END IF; 
        END
```